# Printable Area Error

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, headers, microsoft-word-2011

I have a Microsoft Word .docx file that I am attempting to print in Microsoft Word for Mac 2011.

After I click print, I receive an error that says

> A header of section 1 is set outside the printable area of the page. Do you want to continue?

When I proceed, the page prints normally, with nothing cut off. I cannot seem to figure out what is causing this problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The page top margin is probably too small. You don't notice it when printing if the space before for the header paragraph format is large enough (as it will be just white space that is chopped off).

Comment: @DavidPostill I have adjusted the top margin and it has not worked.

Comment: (1) To see if some margins are too large, go to the Home tab, click on Margins and choose Custom margins. You can then see which margins are too small, or if not - add their screenshot to the post. (2) Look on same tab at the Size - the default page-size might be too small. (3) In the View tab, set the mode to Print layout, and maybe you could see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yes, the default settings. This will always happen unless you manually set your margins to accommodate all printing area(s). You might have a header or footer set too low or too high. You might have put some text-art, text-box, or art, image, etc, too far over a margin. Word is reminding you that your margins are being compromised. Yes, usually your prints will come out fine, but it's detecting a margin overlay somewhere. That's all it is.